Find values of x for which this series converges
I am having some troubles with this exercise :
“Let $\displaystyle a_n = \int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{xe^x}dx$.
Find all the values of $x$ for which the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n (x+2)^n$ converges”
I have been thinking this for several days, and I cannot find a solution for this. The main trouble is the integral $a_n$.
By mean value theorem for integrals I know that $\displaystyle \int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{xe^x}dx = \frac{1}{ce^c}$ for some $c \in [n,n+1]$ , so I was trying to use that fact in combination with D'Alembert criteria to solve the problem : $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} =  \dfrac{ce^c}{de^d} $ for $d \in [n+1,n+2]$, but I think this will go to nowhere.
I would like some help  to solve this problem.Thanks.

I think the needed augmentation is to use integration by parts to write $a_n$ as (a term that's $n^{-1}e^{-n}$ up to at most constant factors) plus $\int_n^{n+1} x^{-2}e^{-x},dx$, which will allow for a more precise evaluation of $a_{n+1}/a_n$.

Let $y=-x-2$ ; then the question is equivalent to determine the values of $y$ for which the power series $\sum a_n y^n$ is-defined. Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of this power series.
First, one has $0 \leq a_n \leq \dfrac{1}{ne^n}$ so for every $y \in [0,e]$, the sequence $(a_ny^n)_{n\geq 0}$ tends to $0$.
This implies that $R \geq e$.
But one has also $a_n \geq \dfrac{1}{(n+1)e^{n+1}}$, so $a_ne^n \geq \dfrac{1}{(n+1)e}$ which is the general term of a divergent series.
So the radius satisfies $R \leq e$.
These two inequalities give that $\boxed{R=e}$. It remains to study the convergence of $\sum a_ny^n$ for $y=e$ and $y=-e$.
But we already proved that $\sum a_n e^n$ is divergent, so it remains to study the convergence of $\sum a_n (-e)^n$. One has :
$$a_ne^n = \int_n^{n+1} \dfrac{1}{xe^{x-n}}dx =\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{(x+n)e^x}dx$$
so $(a_ne^n)_{n \geq 0}$ decreases and tends to $0$, so the series $\sum (-1)^na_ne^n$ is convergent by Leibniz test.
Finally, $\sum a_ny^n$ converges iff $y \in [-e,e[$, so $\sum (-1)^na_n(x+2)^n$ converges iff
$$\boxed{x \in ]-e-2, e-2]}$$
